# How to access uploaded files from views

Tags: zend-framework2

All the uploaded files are stored under

```
__namespace__/src/__namespace/Controller/logos/file.jpg
```

and controller file returns only file name "file.jpg" in the view.

So how can I provide path to logo folder in my view in IMG tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where you made the first "Error"! **Never store user-data inside your Modules!**

When you have users upload data for your module, store them under `/data/module-name/`! That way you can easily access the files via `src="../data/module-name/filename.jpg"`

Alternatively, when you want to provide files with your Module and be able to use them, theres a great Module out there called [`AssetManager`](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager), which in turn uses [`Assetic`](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic).